# Cannot load the csv file using d3.csv

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to load a CSV file using d3.csv and trying to print the data on console.
But on the console it prints null in Mozilla Firefox and it says cannot load the file in google chrome.
[This is what it looks like in Mozilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoDRM.jpg)

```
This is what my code is 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> data visuaization project </title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
d3.csv("PopulationEstimates.csv", function(data){
console.log(data);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The data file is a .Xls file which I saved in .csv format

This is the link for the site where I found the dataset
 https://www.ers.usda.gov/webdocs/DataFiles/CountyLevel_Data_Sets_Download_Data__18026/PopulationEstimates.xls?v=42489

Comment: Are you using a server?

Comment: Did you remove the first two lines of the xls?

Comment: Ye, I did remove the first two lines

Comment: I'm not using a server since d3 can be run using a basic HTML page @Gerardo Furtado

Comment: This has nothing to do with D3. The browser will not allow you to load a local file. Have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Introduction#restrictions

Comment: The data is being lade by disabling the security feature in chrome